# Kindly find below the screenshot of the application "I was talking" about

Tags: past-continuous

I'm working as IT support engineer. one of my clients phoned me last week and explained to me a problem that he had on one of our applications that we support.

then he sent me an email and the following is the first sentence:

> Kindly find below the screenshot of the application **I was talking** about. The issue is as follows:

I'm wondering is the above correct use of past continuous, I think the simple past is better in this context, isn't it?

> Kindly find below the screenshot of the application **I told you** about.

Comment: Using "I told you" might come across as condescending, depending on the relationship between the parties. Something like when a mother tells her children "**I told you** to take off your shoes before coming inside." I would avoid it in a formal business situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you received with **I was talking about** is perfectly idiomatic. The past continuous there refers obliquely to your earlier *conversation* in which he described the problem.  It bears the added nuance that now you have in hand something which will help you to understand my *earlier words* more completely.

As you say, "*phoned* ... then he sent me an email".

Compared to the simple past **told**, the continuous **was telling** puts a little extra emphasis on the *durational act* of telling, as distinct from an incident without duration. Thus, it might be paraphrased "as I assume you do remember from our recent conversation, which should not yet have shrunk down to a mere dot in your mind" as might well happen with the passage of time. With time, you might remember only that you two had spoken but not the *conversation*.

The continuous implies that the speaker fully expects this matter to be *fresh* in your mind. He expects you to remember the conversation. For that reason, the simple past is not better.